# Azure function triggered by service bus topic doesn't work

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am creating an azure function that is triggered using service bus topic using .Net 6.0. I am trying to run it on my local but it seems that the trigger is not working. I added message to my topic but the function didn't get call.

Azure Function

```
[FunctionName("TestFunction")]
        public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("test-topic", "test-sub", Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")] string messageBodyAsString,
    ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"C# function triggered to process a message: {messageBodyAsString}");
        }
```

local.settings.json

```
 {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsServiceBus": "Endpoint="

  }
```

Comment: Is the message in the `test-sub` subscription? If not, here's your answer. Otherwise, there's something wrong with the setup because the function is barebones functional should work.

Comment: Yes, there is a message. If I deploy it in Azure it is working fine but when I run it in my local it doesn't work(trigger not firiing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if works in azure and you can't debug locally, it could be either firewall or proxy' try first adding "transportType": "amqpWebSockets" to your host.json. that will solve the firewall problem if that is the only problem. Sometimes the proxy can block WebSockets

[image]